# Matcher.find() returns false even though a match exists

Tags: java, matcher

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7wI6.png):

```java
String next_line = " I MQ (AELTPHQXRU) (BKNW) (CMOY) (DFG) (IV) (JZ) (S)"

String regex_cycle = "\\([\\s()a-zA-Z]+\\)";       #matches "(AELTPHQXRU) (BKNW) (CMOY) (DFG) (IV) (JZ) (S)"

String regex_rotorName = "^[^\\s()RNM]+";          #matches "I"

String regex_rotorDescriptor = "^[MNR][^\\s()]*";  #matches "MQ"

Matcher name_matcher = Pattern.compile(regex_rotorName).matcher(next_line);
Matcher cycle_matcher = Pattern.compile(regex_cycle).matcher(next_line);
Matcher descriptor_matcher = Pattern.compile(regex_rotorDescriptor).matcher(next_line);

System.out.println(name_matcher.find());
System.out.println(cycle_matcher.find());
System.out.println(descriptor_matcher.find());
```

For some reason, my `matcher.find()`'s are returning false.

As seen in the image, `next_line` equals `" I MQ    (AELTPHQXRU) (BKNW) (CMOY) (DFG) (IV) (JZ) (S)."`.

All three `find()`s should return true based on this string right?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. People need to be able to copy & paste your code and try it. See [ask].

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your regexes are supposed to match, but I would advice you to check https://regex101.com/. That website can help you form the correct regex for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be calling `find()` in System.out statements immediately before the `if` so that they are reporting the second matches, not first match.

Assign to local variable and use the values in `System.out.println` and `if`